# Phaser 3 Animation order/priority

Tags: javascript, animation, phaser-framework

I'm currently try to add animations to my game and until now it workey okay,
but now I got a problem and I think I lost the overview a bit.

**My controls:**
W - Look up
A - Walk left
D - Walk right
Space - Jump
E hold - charge shot (for animations: hold gun while staying/runing/jumping)
E release - shot

My Problem:
All animations are fine so far, if I use any control key and press E afterwards.
The problem is, if I hold E first and *then* press any ther key, the current animation doesn't change.
Same if I press any key like walking left, press and hold E and release walking while holding E.
Only exception is, if I hold E first and press W. Then the look up animation will play.
But if I release W while holding E, it's stuck in look up animation again.

My Animation/player control code:

```
playerControlUpdate() {
    if (this.setUIOnce) {
        this.setUpUI();
        this.setUIOnce = false;
    }

    //Fullscreen
    if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.key_F)) {

        if (this.scene.scale.isFullscreen) {
            this.scene.scale.stopFullscreen();
        }
        else {
            this.scene.scale.startFullscreen();
        }
    };

    //movement
    if (this.key_A.isDown) {
        this.setVelocityX(this.pace * -1);
        this.setFlipX(true);
        this.playerDirection = "left";
        if (this.body.touching.down) {
            this.currentFrame = this.anims.currentFrame.index;
            if (this.key_E.isDown) {
                if(this.anims.currentAnim.key == 'walkRight') {
                    if (this.currentFrame >= 13 || this.currentFrame <= 0) {
                        this.play({ key: 'shootWalk', startFrame: 1 }, true);
                    }
                    else {

                        this.play({ key: 'shootWalk', startFrame: this.currentFrame }, true);
                    }
                }

            }
            else {
                if (this.anims.currentAnim.key == 'shootWalk') {
                    if (this.currentFrame >= 13 || this.currentFrame <= 0) {
                        console.log(this.currentFrame);
                        this.play({ key: 'walkRight', startFrame: 1 }, true);
                    }
                    else {

                        this.play({ key: 'walkRight', startFrame: this.currentFrame }, true);
                    }


                }
                else {
                    this.anims.play('walkRight', true);
                }
            }
        }

        
    }
    else if (this.key_D.isDown) {
        this.setVelocityX(this.pace);
        this.setFlipX(false);
        this.playerDirection = "right";
        if (this.body.touching.down) {
            this.currentFrame = this.anims.currentFrame.index;
            if (this.key_E.isDown) {
                if (this.anims.currentAnim.key == 'walkRight') {
                    if (this.currentFrame >= 13 || this.currentFrame <= 0) {
                        console.log(this.currentFrame);
                        this.play({ key: 'shootWalk', startFrame: 1 }, true);
                    }
                    else {

                        this.play({ key: 'shootWalk', startFrame: this.currentFrame }, true);
                    }
                }
                
            }
            else {
                if (this.anims.currentAnim.key == 'shootWalk') {
                    if (this.currentFrame >= 13 || this.currentFrame <= 0) {
                        console.log(this.currentFrame);
                        this.play({ key: 'walkRight', startFrame: 1 }, true);
                    }
                    else {

                        this.play({ key: 'walkRight', startFrame: this.currentFrame }, true);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    this.anims.play('walkRight', true);
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    else {
        this.setVelocityX(0);
        if (this.body.touching.down && !this.key_E.isDown && this.anims.currentAnim.key != 'shootStay_release' && !this.anims.isPaused && this.anims.currentAnim.key != 'shootUp') {
            if (this.playerDirection == "left") {
                this.setFlipX(true);
                this.anims.play('idle', true);
            }
            else if (this.playerDirection == "right") {
                this.setFlipX(false);
                this.anims.play('idle', true);
            }
        }
        
    }

    if (this.key_W.isDown && !(this.key_A.isDown || this.key_D.isDown)) {
        if (this.anims.currentAnim.key != 'shootUp' && this.body.touching.down) {
            this.anims.play('lookUp', true);
        }
    }
    if (!this.body.touching.down) {
        this.currentFrame = this.anims.currentFrame.index;
        if (this.key_W.isDown) {
            if (this.anims.currentAnim.key == 'jump' || this.anims.currentAnim.key == 'shootJump') {
                if (this.currentFrame >= 8 || this.currentFrame <= 0) {
                    console.log(this.currentFrame);
                    this.play({ key: 'upJump', startFrame: 1 }, true);
                }
                else {

                    this.play({ key: 'upJump', startFrame: this.currentFrame }, true);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (this.key_E.isDown) {
            if (this.anims.currentAnim.key == 'jump' || this.anims.currentAnim.key == 'upJump') {
                if (this.currentFrame >= 8 || this.currentFrame <= 0) {
                    console.log(this.currentFrame);
                    this.play({ key: 'shootJump', startFrame: 1 }, true);
                }
                else {

                    this.play({ key: 'shootJump', startFrame: this.currentFrame }, true);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (this.anims.currentAnim.key == 'upJump' || this.anims.currentAnim.key == 'shootJump') {
                if (this.currentFrame >= 8 || this.currentFrame <= 0) {
                    console.log(this.currentFrame);
                    this.play({ key: 'jump', startFrame: 1 }, true);
                }
                else {

                    this.play({ key: 'jump', startFrame: this.currentFrame }, true);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }


    if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.key_SPACE)) {
        if (this.body.touching.down) {
            this.setVelocityY(this.jumpPower);
            if (this.key_W.isDown) {
                this.anims.play('upJump', true);
            }
            else if (this.key_E.isDown) {
                this.anims.play('shootJump', true);
            }
            else {
                this.anims.play('jump', true);
            }
            
        }
    }

    //Weapons
    if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.key_E)) {
        this.bigShot = this.scene.time.now + 700;
        if (this.key_W.isDown ) {
            this.playAfterRepeat('lookUp');
        }
        else {
            if (this.anims.currentAnim.key != 'shootStay_release' && !this.anims.isPaused && !(this.key_A.isDown || this.key_D.isDown) && this.body.touching.down) { // touching ground bei jumpshoot ggf anpassen
                this.anims.play('shootStay_hold', true);
            }
            else {
                if (this.body.velocity.x == 0) {
                    this.playAfterRepeat('shootStay_hold');
                }
                
            }
        }

    }

    if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustUp(this.key_E)) {
        if (this.body.touching.down) {
            if (this.key_W.isDown) {
                this.anims.play('shootUp', true);
                this.playAfterRepeat('lookUp');
            }
            else if (this.key_A.isDown || this.key_D.isDown) {}
            else {
                this.anims.play('shootStay_release', true);
                this.playAfterRepeat('idle');
            }
        }
        
        if (this.weaponInUse == 1) {
            this.useWeaponOne();
        }
        else {
            this.useWeaponTwo();
        }

    }

    if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.key_C)) {
        if (this.weaponCD > this.scene.time.now) { return; } // big shot
        else {
            this.weaponInUse = this.weaponInUse * -1;
            this.scene.registry.set("playerWeaponInUse", this.weaponInUse);     //später entfernen. Muss nur bei Szenenwechsel gespeichert werden (wenn überhaupt).
            eventEmitter.emit('activeWeapon', this.weaponInUse);
            eventEmitter.emit('weaponCD', this.weaponCooldown);
            this.scene.time.addEvent(this.timedEvent);
            this.weaponCD = this.scene.time.now + this.weaponCooldown;
        }
    }



    if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.key_X)) {
    }

    
}
```

I hope some new perspectives/views can help me. :)
If anyone knows a better way to sort animations, I would appreciate it too.
I know my order is very... chaotic.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the second parameter in the `play` function. This parameter tells phaser **not to play the animation**, when it is playing already ([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Animations.AnimationState.html#play__anchor), *or checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70975674/what-is-the-phaser-3-animation-managers-anims-play-second-parameter-for)*).

You just could remove the parameter or set it to `false` *(but only on the shoot animations, and/or where I would make sense)*.