# What is the Phaser 3 Animation Manager's anims.play() second parameter for?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I've followed [the tutorial on the Phaser website](https://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-3-game/part1) for making a basic platforming game, but I've had difficulty finding good documentation on how they play animations.

When they call:

`player.anims.play('left', true);`

they pass a boolean for the second parameter,
but later when they call:

`player.anims.play('turn');`

they don't pass anything.

What is the function of this parameter, and is it false by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in the [documentation of the function](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Animations.AnimationState.html#play__anchor) `play`, you can see that the second parameter is `ignoreIfPlaying`. This parameter tells phaser, if it should ignore the specific function call, if the animation is playing.

> ... *If this animation is already playing then ignore this call. ...*

And yes, the default value is `false`, for this parameter.

The documentation is a bit difficult to navigate since the functions/object are defined different, as one would use it in code.